# What are some tips on refactoring lifecycle component methods into useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, refactoring

I am trying to refactor the following into ES6 as a functional component. I considered looking into lodash decorators: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-decorators#bind but are there tips on approaching refactoring class components like this to functional components compliant with ES6, especially when the logic in the lifecycle component methods get more complex?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.state = {
            profilePictureFailedToLoad: false,
   
        };
        if (process.browser) {
            this.profileImage = new Image();
            this.profileImage.src = this.props.userInfo.userAssetUrl;
        }
        this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
        this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
        this.handleProfileClick = this.handleProfileClick.bind(this);
        this.handleModalClose = this.handleModalClose.bind(this);
        this.handleDeleteAccountClick = this.handleDeleteAccountClick.bind(this);
        this.handleDeleteAccountModalClose = this.handleDeleteAccountModalClose.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.router.query.login === "true" && prevProps.router.query.login !== "true") {
        console.log("Updating...")
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Eden.

I think that code is an abstraction of a production code. Right? A real code example would be easier but let's try to help:

Moving from class components to function components with hooks isn't too easy to picture in the beginning.

> The _isMounted flag.

I do not know how that flag is used but you might not need it. If you do, you can use an useRef inside + useEffect;

I have to emphasize you probably do not need this implementation:

```
const ref = React.useRef(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    // This will run only in the first render;
    ref.current = true;
    () => {
        ref.current = false;            
    }
}, [])
```

> The componentDidUpdate

In case you need to render a loading instead of that console.log, you can move this logic to the return (render) part of the function component.

> The handlers

You can probably attach them to each correspondent element. You can use React.useCallback to avoid child components to rerender if that makes sense to you.

> The profileImage

How would that be used? I also believe this can co to the rendering part.

I do hope that can give you some good direction.